# When installing Kwikset lock part of the shaft of the lock collides with the bolt

Tags: lock

The red box in the picture shows that the semicircular metal cutout on the bolt for the perpendicular shaft of the lock is in the way

[image]

I know this is not a manufacturing defect because the earlier Kwikset has the same colliding structure. So what am I misunderstanding here and how to install this part correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cutout" where you're getting interference is a normal part of the latch mechanism.  It needs to slide/retract slightly when you first assemble the pieces.

Here is a nice video demonstration:

https://youtu.be/bsgpomUQcy0?t=410

Comment: i don't believe that were mentioned anywhere in the instructions.